# how to make this "div" always visible to users

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

On my site, I have an ajax call to my server that checks if a certain logged in user has a new message from the database.This ajax script checks the database every certain seconds.And if he/she has a new message, I execute this javascript to create a "div" to  display to the user.Here is the javascript:

```
function shownotice(b) { 
divnotice = document.createElement("div");
 var a = document.createElement("a");
a.onclick = this.close; 
a.href = "#"; 
a.setAttribute("Id", "close");
 a.className = "close";
 a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("close")); 
divnotice.appendChild(a); 
divnotice.className = "notifier"; 
divnotice.setAttribute("Id", "divnotice");
 divnotice.setAttribute("align", "center"); 
document.body.appendChild(divnotice);
 divnotice.style.top = document.body.scrollTop + "px";
 divnotice.style.left = document.body.scrollLeft + "px"; 
divnotice.style.display = "block"; 
createframe(divnotice); 
 }
```

And my css for this div:

```
div.notifier
{
padding:10px;
position:absolute;
display:none;
top:0px;
left:0px;
height:auto;
width:auto;
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black
}
```

My question is that how can I make this "div" always visible to the user even he/she scrolls down.Like for example a user is viewing the bottom of the page, he/she can't see the "div".In other words I would like the "div" to be visible to the user no matter where is his/her scrolling position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `{position:fixed}` style as well. That will make the top and left be relative to the browser viewport.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
  div.notifier {
       padding:10px;
       height:auto;
       width:auto;
       background-color:white;
       border:1px solid black
       position:fixed;
       top: /*Put the value you want here*/ ;
       left: /*Put the value you want here, if you want to put the div on the right you should use right instead of left*/ ;
   }
```

Comment: +1 for Great answer with detail, but you need to indent your code block with at least four spaces so everyone can read it clearly, and be able to immediately see it is code. If you want to make just a single word in code, use backticks around the word or phrase.